# How can I change the brightness of only part of an image (html/css/js)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have an image with tags underneath that correspond to different parts of the image. For instance, the image might be a dog, and one of the tags is 'nose', which corresponds to the portion of the image around the dogs nose. When the user hovers over a tag, I want the brightness around this corresponding part of the image to increase. How can I do this?

```js
function fixLabel(c) {
  var x_coor = document.getElementById('x').textContent;
  var y_coor = document.getElementById('y').textContent;

  var x2_coor = document.getElementById('x2').textContent;
  var y2_coor = document.getElementById('y2').textContent;

  var width = document.getElementById('w').textContent;
  var height = document.getElementById('h').textContent;

  var tag = document.createElement('input'); // Create a `input` element,
  tag.setAttribute('type', 'text'); // Set it's `type` attribute,
  tag.setAttribute('name', 'loc:' + round_2_decimals(x_coor) + "-" + round_2_decimals(y_coor) + "-" +
    round_2_decimals(x2_coor) + "-" + round_2_decimals(y2_coor) + "-" + round_2_decimals(width) +
    "-" + round_2_decimals(height));

  /**
   *Here's the area: How do I attach a mouseover function so the image's 
   *brightness increases whenever I hover over the tag?
   */
  tag.onmouseover = function() {};

  var br = document.createElement('br'); // Create a `br` element,
  var button_div = document.getElementById('fix_label_area');
  button_div.appendChild(br);
  button_div.appendChild(tag);
  button_div.appendChild(br);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <p id='x'></p>
  <p id='y'></p>
  <p id='x2'></p>
  <p id='y2'></p>
  <p id='w'></p>
  <p id='h'></p>
  <br/>
  <button id='fix_label' onclick="fixLabel()">Fix Label Here</button>
</div>

<form action="" method="POST" id="canvas">
  <div id='img_area'>
    <img src="someImageFile.jpg" id="imageId" width="350" height="350" />
  </div>
  <div id='label_area'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Label" id='input'>
  </div>
  <div id='fix_label_area'></div>
</form>
```

Comment: probably your best bet is looking into canvas

Comment: You could also use SVG or CSS.

Comment: Probably best bet would be to either use an svg or canvas, if you want to use standard images and css, then you could use an image map on the main image and as you hover certain parts, absolute position the highlighted version over the correct area

Answer (score 4):

Personally Canvas and SVG are more powerful, but you can use CSS to clip a circle and opacity to dim the original. But you need to check the [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility) to make sure it covers the browsers you need.

```css
div.holder {
  position: relative;
}

img.main {
  opacity: .4;
}

img.circle {
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: circle(50px at 405px 135px);
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <img class="circle" src="https://placedog.net/500" />
  <img class="main" src="https://placedog.net/500" />
</div>
```

Comment: Placekitten please.